# sqlite3 run sql - select all with PUA characters

Tags: unicode, sqlite

How can I run a:

SELECT * FROM tablename

where column contains PUA character.

[PUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas)

**Private Use Areas**

> In Unicode, a Private Use Area (PUA) is a range of code points that, by definition, will not be assigned characters by the Unicode Consortium.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) Currently, three private use areas are defined: one in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+E000–U+F8FF), and one each in, and nearly covering, planes 15 and 16 (U+F0000–U+FFFFD, U+100000–U+10FFFD). The code points in these areas cannot be considered as standardized characters in Unicode itself. They are intentionally left undefined so that third parties may define their own characters without conflicting with Unicode Consortium assignments. Under the Unicode Stability Policy,[2] the Private Use Areas will remain allocated for that purpose in all future Unicode versions.
>
> Assignments to Private Use Area characters need not be "private" in the sense of strictly internal to an organisation; a number of assignment schemes have been published by several organisations. Such publication may include a font that supports the definition (showing the glyphs), and software making use of the private-use characters (e.g. a graphics character for a "print document" function). By definition, multiple private parties may assign different characters to the same code point, with the consequence that a user may see one private character from an installed font where a different one was intended.

Is there anyway I can find this subset of characters in my sqlite table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUA characters are valid Unicode characters; just use them in the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '豈')  -- E000, F900
   OR (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '')  -- F0000, FFFFE
   OR (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < ''); -- 100000, 10FFFE
```

If you cannot insert such characters directly into the query string, use the [char() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#char).

Comment: How to get this to also include characters that are not the first in the ColumnName?

Comment: That would be a different question.

Comment: Maybe not I did ask: where column contains PUA character - I'm only getting results where it's PUA+X but not x+ PUA

Comment: I can't do something like this: WHERE (CHS >= '%""%' AND CHS < '%"豈"%') ?