# sqlite query greater than or equal to with wildcards

Tags: sqlite, search, wildcard

I'm using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '豈')
   OR (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '')
   OR (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '');
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182551/3306356) - but it only returns entries that begin with anything in those ranges.

I need to be able to find entries that don't begin with characters in those ranges **but** contain characters that exist in the above ranges.

I have tried changing

```
'' AND ColumnName < '豈'
```

to

```
'%""%' AND CHS < '%"豈"%'
```

hoping that would work - but it evidently doesn't work like that.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single characters, you could use LIKE, but character ranges require [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnName GLOB '*[-豈]*'
   OR ColumnName GLOB '*[-]*'
   OR ColumnName GLOB '*[-]*';
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with standard SQL would be to include an OR clause for each and every character within your ranges:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE
   ColName LIKE '%X%' OR
   ColName LIKE '%Y%' OR 
   ColName LIKE '%Z%' . . .
```

which is tedious and probably not practical depending on how many characters are in your ranges.

Two other options you can look at are regular expressions, represented in SQLite with the REGEXP operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColName REGEXP 'regular_expression'
```

or else full text search, documented here: http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html.