# Finding PUA characters anywhere in column?

Tags: search, sqlite

I asked a similar question here: [sqlite3 run sql - select all with PUA characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42181599/3306356).

The answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '豈')
   OR (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '')
   OR (ColumnName >= '' AND ColumnName < '');
```

Only works with entries that start with a PUA character.

I'm trying to find a way to find these characters anywhere inside the entries (i.e.: LIKE) but I can't seem to figure out how to do it aside from the above.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for character ranges, you need [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnName GLOB '*[-]*'
   OR ColumnName GLOB '*[-]*'
   OR ColumnName GLOB '*[-]*';
```